# Query String Except a Filed in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm using `query_string` to search a word on documents on indexes. Now, I wanna continue searching on all fields except a considered field!
what can I do? what feature should I use to handle the query?

The query that search on on fields:

```
GET siem-referencedata-list-*/_search
{
  "query": 
  {
    "bool":
    {
      "must":
      [
        {
          "bool": 
          {
            "should": 
            [
              {
                "query_string": 
                {
                  "query": "*list*"
                  
                }
              }
              ]
          }
        }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can ignore searching on a special field (for example `id`)

Note: because my fields are dynamic, I cant search on specific fields. I have three stable fields that don not want search on them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in a `query_string` type query to exclude field while searching. But you can restrict the search on specific fields by giving lists of fields on which search should execute.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
      "fields": ["field1","field2","field3"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can provide regex pattern as well in `fields` like below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "fields" : ["city.*"],
      "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to stop providing search functionality on specific field then you can set `index` to `false` in mapping and elasticsearch will not index specific field and it will just store it. you will be able to retrive field in response:

```json
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user_id": {
        "type":  "keyword"
      },
      "last_updated": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "session_data": { 
        "type": "text",
        "index": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have errors when using `enabled`:
`Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: unknown parameter [enabled] on mapper [desc] of type [text]
unknown parameter [enabled] on mapper [desc] of type [text]`
I tested `index` instead of `enabled` and it was worked. what is difference between `index` and `enabled`? I'm using version `7.12.0`

Comment: Sorry may bad !! `enabled` can only apply to the `object` type of field and `index` is applied to core type of field like `text` etc. You can use `index` param. I will update my answer !!